# Feathered clipping mask for jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

I have a set of images scrolling continuously with jCarousel. Only one image is fully displayed at a time, and I would love to be able to "feather" the edges of the carousel so the images fade in and out as they traverse visibility.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Also, the carousel's motion seems a bit buggy at times. On occasional page loads it seems like the `animation` and/or `auto` parameters in the initialization of the carousel aren't being implemented properly, causing the carousel to either move quicker than expected, or delay longer, etc. Thoughts?

Edit to add: Is there possibly a way, in lieu of a true clipping mask, to use one of jCarousel's callbacks to perform `fadeOut()` on an image as it moves out of the carousel's focus (and then `fadeIn()` as an image moves into focus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://motorhound.com.au/) is an example of jcarousel with feathered edges

Technically it isn't really feathered, there's just  semi transparent PNG over the top. I don't think there is a way to have a true feather

Comment: Thanks @Coomie. That actually uses simplyScroll instead of jCarousel, a plugin I had yet to hear of, but will actually fit my needs much better than jCarousel. So thank you for the inadvertent advice!

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. They're both good. You can trick jCarousel into doing the same thing, but it's so buggy. simplyScroll is waaaaay more stable. Good luck... maybe tick me as answerer...?

Comment: Sure, you earned it. Regarding feathering, I do think I'll just have to put a mask over the top of the carousel to achieve graceful feathering.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to make a transparent PNG with gradients that fade from transparent to the color of the background of your carousel, and use CSS `position:absolute` with a higher `z-index` than the carousel container div to place it on top.  [Here's a page with some examples- pay attention to the transparency section in particular.](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/web_standards_creativity_png/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the carousel has a transparent background, so this isn't possible.